# Should the first letters of tag text be capitalized?

Tags: discussion, tags

A user recently went through a bunch of the country tags and changed the text, deleting the first few words from those that already had text.  As a result, the tag text now starts with an uncapitalized word.  For example, [india](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india):

> for questions about claims based in India, or limited to India.

You can see the [edit history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/31627/revisions).

This also happened for some number of country wiki excerpts that did not have previous text.  Presumably this was a copy paste error.

I went through and capitalized the word on some of the ones already approved, but those edits were rejected, primarily by the user who made the original mistake.

Shouldn't we go ahead and fix this now while it's fresh rather than waiting until later?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly favor correct grammar in all settings where we should expect it. I even go a step further that correcting missed and misplaced capitalization are not minor edits. I favor that we correct these items now.

Grammar is the first indicator of professionalism, and professionalism is a goal for all SE sites. We strive to make the internet a better place and create a space with a high level of signal to noise. To me, and I think to many others, incorrect grammar and lazy capitalization *looks* like noise. In the least, our noise should still look like signal.

This leaves us with this question: where should correct grammar be used. For me, that line is everywhere except where programming requires normalized text. For example, tag *names* are normalized to lowercase because they serve an organizational/programming function. As an amateur programmer and web developer, I actually expect that*. In the tag excerpts, which does not exist for any programming reason, I expect correct grammar. It exists solely to define tags for the end user to understand.

---

For some *smh* feelings for the programmers, [tag synonym search](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is case-sensitive**, which breaks the whole reasoning for normalizing tag names in the first place.

---

<sup>*Oddly, we can perform all normalization behind the scenes, on the fly, but knowing that tags are a programming artefact that happily double-serve as a quasi-meaningful metric leaves most of us with the expectation that it should *look* like a programming thing, even to the end-users. This might make for an interesting study on [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Feel free to follow up there.

**[SE staff are looking into the bug already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330865/is-the-tag-synonyms-search-box-supposed-to-be-case-sensitive), so don't post on meta.</sup>